# Angular Unit - testing (Jasmine karma) : Failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getComplete)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, karma-jasmine

I called getComplete method in component.spec.ts file which is defined in google.directive.ts file.
component.ts:-->

```
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ...
    this.googleComplete.getComplete(this.addresstext);
    console.log('address is:--' , this.addresstext);
```

*googleComplete:--> ComponentPage.googleComplete: GoogleCompleteDirective

component.spec.ts:->

```
it('called getComplete method', waitForAsync(inject([GoogleCompleteDirective],
    ( googleCompleteDirective: GoogleCompleteDirective ) => {
    spyOn(component, 'ngAfterViewInit').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(googleCompleteDirective, 'getComplete').and.callThrough();
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    expect(component.ngAfterViewInit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

google.directive.ts:->

```
getComplete(addresstext: ElementRef) {
//code here....
....
}
```

directive.ts:-

```
getAutocomplete(addresstext: ElementRef) {
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addresstext.nativeElement,
      {
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'US' },
        fields: ['address_components', 'geometry'],
        types: ['address']
      });
```

after testing this code, got Error:->
" Failed: google is not defined

ReferenceError: google is not defined"

I also used  providers:
[ GoogleCompleteDirective,{ provide: ElementRef, useValue: {} }, ]
in provider for elementref and imported getCompleteDirective

Please suggest me the ways to fix this?

It should pass test case but getting Error:->
" Failed: google is not defined

ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Comment: Please show where the error points to, ie. in your snippets, there's no field or variable called `google`.

Comment: I solved the issue related to google and updated questtion. Now, google is defined and  not having any issue related to it. Please have a look and provide solution.

Comment: Sorry, but after re-reading the post, it's still not clear what is what. If there's the `GoogleCompleteDirective` directive, I guess there should be a host component, of which you quoted the `ngAfterViewInit`, but what's the template and what is the constructor? Also, what is the test setup? eg. testing module. This: `providers: [ GoogleCompleteDirective,{ provide: ElementRef, useValue: {} }, ]` sounds fishy, because the directive is not provided with the `provide`, but comes from the template somehow.

Comment: Again I am facing Failed: google is not defined ReferenceError: google is not defined"  error I updated code. Please have a look and provide solution. if I add  
   afterEach(() => {
    (window.google as any) = undefined;
    (window as any).gm_authFailure = undefined;
    });
  then It shows error for maps how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I got solution for the error from [here](https://github.com/prasathmani/google-maps-mock-api/blob/master/gmaps.mock.api.js). The main issue was to define what `google` is? After solving this issue, everything else get solved.
Solution -->
From the given link, copy the required data.
Create a js file in the project and paste the copied data in it.
And the address of this js file in files in `karma.conf.js`.

Comment: Does this just overpassed the error or is it a good solution ?